# Show and grow animation on page load in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div show and then grow to its appropriate size. Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#enlarge').css("visibility", "visible").animate({
    height:681, width:467
}, 1000, "linear", function(){alert("all done");});
```

});

My HTML is simple:

```
    <div id="enlarge"><span>content here</span></div>
```

My CSS is even more simple:

```
#enlarge {
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    background: url(../img/enlarge.png)no-repeat;
    z-index: 3;
    position:absolute;
    top:-50px;
    left:250px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/dVr5J/)

```
<div id="enlarge">
  <span>content here</span>
</div>


#enlarge {
  background: #555;
  height: 0;
  width: 467px;
  z-index: 3;
  position:absolute;
  top:-50px;
  left:250px;
}


$(function() {
  $('#enlarge').animate({ height: '681px' }, 1000, 'linear');
});
```

and if you want to animate both width & height than

```
#enlarge {
  background: #555;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  position:absolute;
  top:-50px;
  left:250px;
}


$(function() {
  $('#enlarge').animate({ height: '681px', width: '467px' }, 1000, 'linear');
});
```

Comment: The animation starts from the left-hand corner and goes down. Do you have any suggestions on how to control the start point of the animation? (i.e. from the bottom to the top)

Comment: Instead `top: -50px;` try setting `bottom: 0;`

Comment: Thanks. That worked...but the "wipe" is going from left to right. Is there a way to control that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#enlarge').animate({
    height:681px,
    width:467px
}, 1000);
```

The .css() call is extraneous. EDIT: thanks for catching the px

Comment: The reason is instead `height:681` you must write `height: '681px'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `opacity` as there is no animation for `visible`, which is a boolean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#enlarge").animate({"opacity": "1", "height":"700px", "width":"467px"},5000);
});
```